# DropdownMenu's dropdownMenuEntries as part of it's body

Tags: flutter

I would like the dropdownMenuEntries of the DropdownMenu to be part of the same entity, not separated:

**Actual resutls:**

[image]

**Desired results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I want to get this result I usually create a boolean variable to check if the dropdown is open or not and change the borderbox based on that.

if(dropdown is open) -> bottomleft and bottomright not circular

else -> all borders circular.

You can add multiple styles based on the dropdown being open or close with this system.

Comment: How could you check if it's open or not?

Answer (score -2):

Hope this can help you :

```
CustomDropdown<String>(
  hintText: _list[0],
  items: _list,
  initialItem: _list[0],
  onChanged: (value) {
    log('changing value to: $value');
  },
);
```

From this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_custom_dropdown).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but at the moment, i dont want to use external package, i want to search for a native solution